# ImportError: No module named latch

Tags: python, import.io

when I run import.io example for an api, like official api document, I got this error.

Furthermore, I input '''pip install latch'''
there is no module called latch in pips.

I fail to find latch package, where I can find? Plz help me.

Answer (score 4):

That latch lib, and all other dependencies, can be found here: https://github.com/import-io/importio-client-libs/tree/master/python/importio

I want anyway to make you are you can use importio APIs without any of those things, you can just use requests or urllib2 to make a rest get/post requests using your api key.

Edit: please note that we are planning to deprecate the import.io client libraries over the coming months and are no longer actively maintaining or improving them. We recommend you check out our new API docs http://api.docs.import.io/?query#!/Query_Methods/queryGet which is what I mention in the second paragraph of my original response.

Answer (score 1):

Latch is not included in `pip` or stock python. I am not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I did find one [`latch` module](https://github.com/naviprojects/latch-sdk-python) in all of everywhere.